# Is it possible to extend built in ViewManagers?

Tags: android, react-native

I would like to create a new UI component in `react-native`, with an underlying `RecyclerView` using a custom layout manager, but creating one from scratch would mean giving up things like these: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html

Is there a way to 'extend' from the built in view managers, so I can keep the core functionality of `ListView` intact, and get what I want just by overriding the layout manager?

Also, I checked the `react-native` source and couldn't really find the view manager for the built in `ListView`, maybe I'm overlooking something and looking in the wrong place?

Comment: What kind of customisation are you trying to do with List view?

Comment: I want to use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html, the current solutions for grids using the flex layouts don't allow for this kind of thing.